# Images dissapearing on mobile device (wordpress theme)

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, themes

The site http://smirit.org/ has got a responsive wordpress template, but the images dissapear (after a few seconds) when you visit the site on a mobile device. Images in header (logo) and slider (bottom).

The original theme doesnt do this, check http://organicthemes.com/demo/profile/

Anyone got an idea?

-- EDIT

It appears that when I use images from an other server they do work. But it's not the server's problem because images on a normal browser work fine.

Comment: i was able to see image in mobile...May be it is problem with ur mobile

Comment: I don't think so, this is reported by 5 people with different phones (samsung, iphone) which 'removes' the images after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Installing WP mobile Detector Plugin which provide you with themes with Images supported...

Comment: Will the theme be the same? It cannot be changed, it has to stay the same.

Comment: This problem has been fixed by installing WP Mobile Detector plugin and duplicating the original theme and using that with the plugin. Thanks Mohammed!